Visual Studio Code issue with running multiple lines of code in terminal
for running only a single line, it is fine. but when running multiple lines, it does not print out the lines correctly and blocking the views for the new line.
Please see the attached image for a better idea of what I am trying to say. The first image is showing the issue and the second image is what it should be - the codes did not block the view in terminal.
I figure this is just an issue of configure/setting somewhere in the app that I can turn on or off.
The language I used is R, and the codes are ran in a R script and results are printed through R Interactive terminal.



What language is this? Please [edit] and add the tag for it. And what extension/feature are you using to run the code in terminal?

it is R, and the codes are ran in a R script and results are printed though the R interactive terminal.

have you tried to look at this docs and installed the R extension? this should help https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r

I did look at that doc but did not find anything.
